# Performance with timestamp conditions

Tags: mysql, performance

Which of the following is faster, or are they equivalent?
(grabbing recent most records from a TIMESTAMP COLUMN)

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`modified`) stamp
FROM `some_table`
HAVING stamp > 127068799
ORDER BY stamp DESC
```

or

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`modified`) stamp
FROM `some_table`
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`modified`) > 127068799
ORDER BY `modified` DESC
```

or even another combination?

Comment: HAVING is intended to be used with GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both equal and not so good ones, as every single row value have to be converted to timestamp

why not to leave date field as is, and convert only constant value?

```
WHERE `modified` > FROM_UNIXTIME(127068799)
```

Comment: I was under the impression that a timestamp column used an integer internally and so using UNIX_TIMESTAMP had no overhead. Can somebody here confirm that either way?

Comment: just noticed you can also do:
`modified`+0

Comment: @Tim may be some smart optimizer does this conversion automatically, but I wouldn't rely on this. Why to use some silent magic, when we can write plain and straight condition instead?

Comment: fair enough point, so are you saying that:
    `modified` > FROM_UNIXTIME(123456)
incurs less overhead than:
    `modified`+0 > 127068799
?

Comment: I can see now, from running some EXPLAIN SELECTs, that using modified+0 prevents the use of the index, so I guess that answers my question
thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

As long as `modified` is indexed, this one:

```
SELECT  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`modified`) stamp
FROM    `some_table`
WHERE   modified > FROM_UNIXTIME(127068799)
ORDER BY
        modified DESC
```

is the best solution, since it is sargable and allows the index on `modified` to be used, unlike both of your queries.

Comment: thanks. I see your point about using the index.
my only issue remaining is which conversion functions have the least overhead. I don't quite follow why FROM_UNIXTIME is used when the column stores an integer internally. See above comment thread